How to handle multiple connections to microservice behind LoadBalancer
If there is a restful microservice A which has 50 instances of the same services, and if each instance can handle a million concurrent connections, total 50 instances can handle around 50 million concurrent connections.
If there is a loadbalancer in front of this microservice A, can the loadbalancer manage all these connections?
Since client connects to the loadbalancer and the requests are relayed to one of the instances of microservice A. So esentially all the 50 million concurrent connections go to the load balancer first before they are relayed to the service.

It is difficult to answer your question without more details on your infrastructure.
Your only way to get the answer is to test it yourself.
However, if you have this type of problem, you can have several replicated loadbalancers. And the more traffic you have, the more you increase the number of loadbalancers.
If you really plan to have 50 million concurrent requests, this is probably the right direction.

@vjk I think what you are eluding to is that the load balancer will now become an overhead? Managing 50 mil instances? If so YES. It is for that matter that you balance the load balancer, have more load balancers, possibly segmented by service categories or regions, to distribute the load more evenly. Service mesh ? dynamically scale ? CDN ? Not sure if it helps. (Edited for grammatical errors)
